# SymPy instance of a set symbol

Tags: sympy

Given a set in SymPy, how can we initialize an instance of this set?

something that will replace this `*...*` and produce these results:

```
>>> a = *new member of ConditionSet(x, x**2 > 4, Interval(2, 4))*
>>> (a + 4)/2 in ConditionSet(x, x**2 > 4, Interval(2, 4))
True
>>> a + 1 in ConditionSet
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: did not evaluate to a bool: None
```

This should reflect the fact that if `a` is in the described set then so is `(a+4)/2` but that's not necessarily true for `a+1`

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking for but it sounds like you're asking for this which is not possible: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18497

Comment: That's exactly how I imagined it, though, can we do this by initializing symbols with constraints, like `is_integer=True`,  only with a custom constraint? Or if not, is it recommended to extend the SymPy symbols to have this functionality? I mean, is there some logical problem here that makes it hard to implement that is the reason there is no such option, or is it just not so widely used hence not implemented, but can be implemented by extending the SymPy symbols module?

Comment: Sometimes you can formulate an expression involving symbols with specific assumptions e.g. if you want a symbol `x` such that `x > 1` then you can replace `x` with `1+y` where `y` is declared positive. This does not always work though. You can of course make your own Symbol class but then you would also need to make your own ConditionSet class that could understand what your Symbol class was.